# How to pass parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I want to pass one parameter to a function called `ForPaste()`.

My function is given below:

```
 var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9ĀĒĪŌŪāēīōū\.\-\~\`\'' ]*$/;
    var SalaryRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9\,\.\/\$ ]*$/;
        $.fn.ForPaste = function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).bind('input propertychange', function () {
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if (!regex.test(value)) {
                        $(this).val("");
                    }
                });
            });
        };
```

This function is in a common JS file. It is called on individual pages. I want to test the regex depending on the parameter passed. So can I know the method about to call the `ForPaste()` function with the parameter.e.g `$("#Text1").Forpaste('FromForm1');` and I get this `FromForm1` in the `ForPaste()` function.

Comment: K T - why have you accepted only 4 answers for you 16 questions? And why do you ignore any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a *formal parameter* for your function.

```
      // formal parameter--v
$.fn.ForPaste = function (the_value) {

    alert( the_value ); // displays the argument passed

    // rest of your code
};
```

Whatever value was passed to `ForPaste()` will be referenced by `the_value`. *(Of course you can change the name to any valid identifier.)*

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do, because the answer seems so obvious. Will this do?

```
$.fn.ForPaste = function (theName) {
    if (theName.test(//)){
        return this.each(function () {
            ....
        });
    }
    return false
};
```

you can access the parameters by looking at `arguments` which isn't an array, but seems to be one. from within the function you can do an `var theName=arguments[0]` to get the value of the first parameter